# x2go Connection failed. bash: bash: command not found

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I want to connect from my home pc with VPN (ubuntu-18.04) to work pc (ubuntu 18.04) using x2go.

Server side installation:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:x2go/stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install x2goserver x2goserver-xsession
```

Client side installation:

```
sudo apt-get install x2goclient
```

I am able to ssh to my remote desktop, but x2go doesn't work. Problem seems to be in the server side, since I tried to x2go connect from different computer (CentOs) and error was the same.

Client session preferences window:
[image]

I tried almost everything in session preferences, even with RSA key (I have it) or single application session type and many else, always the same error.

[image]

Client debug log: (x2goclient --debug)

> x2go-INFO-1> "Starting X2Go Client 4.1.2.1..." x2go-WARNING-1> English
> language requested, not loading translator. x2go-WARNING-1> English
> language requested, not loading translator. Object::connect: No such
> slot ONMainWindow::slotCheckAgentProcess() x2go-INFO-3> "Started X2Go
> Client." x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:563> "$HOME=/home/XXX"
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2242> Reading 1 sessions from
> config file. x2go-DEBUG-../src/sessionbutton.cpp:342> Creating QPixmap
> with session icon: ":/img/icons/128x128/x2gosession.png".
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:12843> libssh not initialized yet.
> Initializing. x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2728> Creating
> QPixmap with session icon: '":/img/icons/128x128/x2gosession.png"'.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2795> Starting session via Smart
> Card, SSH Agent or Kerberos token. x2go-INFO-8> "Starting connection
> to server: 192.168.29.15:22" x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2829>
> Starting new ssh connection to server:"192.168.29.15":"22" krbLogin:
> false x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:175>
> SshMasterConnection, host "192.168.29.15"; port 22; user "XXX";
> useproxy false; proxyserver "192.168.29.15"; proxyport 22
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:248> Starting SSH connection
> without Kerberos authentication.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:252> SshMasterConnection,
> instance SshMasterConnection(0x56102247dbe0)  created.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:520> SshMasterConnection,
> instance SshMasterConnection(0x56102247dbe0)  entering thread.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:840> Session port before
> config file parse: 22 x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:850>
> Session port after config file parse: 22
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:915> Session port before
> config file parse (part 2): 22
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:925> Session port after
> config file parse (part 2): 22
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:950> cserverAuth
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:991> state: 1
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1364> userAuthAuto failed:""
> (code 1)
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1274> Trying password
> mechanism if available.
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1278> Password mechanism
> available. Continuing.
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:726> User authentication OK.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1789> LOGIN CHECK:"LOGIN OK
> " x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1792> don't have
> interaction x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1825> LOOP
> FINISHED x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1829> No
> interaction needed, continue session
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:735> Login Check - OK
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:2923> SSH connection established.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3336> Continue normal X2Go session
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:199> Executing remote command via
> SshProcess object 0: "x2golistsessions"
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:213> this=SshProcess(0x5610224a1f30)
> Running masterCon->addChannelConnection(this, '
> "1d4dfc1a-7f4d-4f00-b39e-07273d3d973d" ', ' "bash -l -c 'echo
> "X2GODATABEGIN:1d4dfc1a-7f4d-4f00-b39e-07273d3d973d"; export
> PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";export TERM="dumb";
> x2golistsessions; echo "X2GODATAEND:1d4dfc1a-7f4d-4f00-b39e-07273d"
> ');  x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1891> Locking SSH
> channel connection MUTEX.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1893> Passing new channel
> connection object to channelConnections.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:1895> Unlocking SSH channel
> connection MUTEX. x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2083>
> Creating new channel.
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2100> New
> channel:0x7fcf84012aa0
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2185> Executing remote:
> "bash -l -c 'echo
> "X2GODATABEGIN:1d4dfc1a-7f4d-4f00-b39e-07273d3d973d"; export
> PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin";export TERM="dumb";
> x2golistsessions; echo
> "X2GODATAEND:1d4dfc1a-7f4d-4f00-b39e-07273d3d973d";'"
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2208> New exec channel
> created.
>
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2257> EOF on channel
> 0x7fcf84012aa0; SshProcess object: 0
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2380> EOF sent.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshmasterconnection.cpp:2384> Channel closed.
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:526> SSH finished: raw output
> (stdout): "" x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:532> Have stderr only,
> something must be wrong. x2go-DEBUG-../src/sshprocess.cpp:537> SSH
> finished: false - "bash: bash: command not found " (0).
> x2go-DEBUG-../src/onmainwindow.cpp:3804> "bash: bash: command not
> found

If someone was interested, I can show server's side /var/log/syslog

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Please try moving your .bashrc aside and retry.

Comment: Ok, some more tips:  Let's rule out gnome first. Create a new session and instead of choosing gnome select "Application" for the session type. In the rightmost test field enter the path to xterm on your server (be sure to install xterm there). If that is working there is a problem with the gnome session setup. You can also try to disable "auto-login" and see if that changes anything. The message bash: bash: command not found" could mean bash is not in your path or not installed, please check that, too.

Comment: I selected Application but instead of xterm I choosed firefox (my friend works like that) and it didn't work. Also tried disable auto-login, didn't worked. And I use bash normally on both computers so I don't know how I couldn't have bash installed. How do I check if it is on classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It was my bad, silly me. I had a typo in /etc/environment file and I didn't notice it because I haven't restarted my PC after that typo. After fixing it, it worked.